# Issues with errors in Comparable implementation

Tags: java

I'm doing an assignment for class where we are comparing an array of objects `Customer` and then offer the user a number of methods. I keep getting an error that says "Customer is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo (Customer) in `java.lang.Comparable`. I'm sorry if this has been dealt with on this forum, but I have had trouble finding an answer that has made all of this sensical.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;


class prog4 {
public static void main(String args[]) 
            throws FileNotFoundException
{
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

Customer [] A =readArray(); //read data into objects in A

while(true)
{
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Please select one of the follwing actions: ");
  System.out.println("q - Quit"); 
  System.out.println("a - List the customer records sorted by customer name"); 
  System.out.println("b - Enter a customer name to find the customer's record"); 
  System.out.println("c - List the customer records sorted by purchase in descending order"); 
  System.out.println("Please enter q, a, b, or c: ");

  String selection=kb.nextLine();  //read user's selection
  if (selection.equals("")) continue; //break; //if selection is "", show menu again

  switch (selection.charAt(0))
  {
    /*write code to process the following cases*/

    case 'a':

            break;

    case 'b':

            break;

    case 'c':

            break;

    case 'q':

            return;

    default:
  } //end switch
} //end while
 } //end main();


  //the following method uses the data from indata.txt
  //to create Customer objects of an array
  //and returns the array

  private static Customer[] readArray()
                  throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    String name;
    double purchase;
    double rebate;

    Scanner infile=new Scanner(new File("indata.txt")); //input file

    int size=infile.nextInt();  //get number of lines
    infile.nextLine();          //skips end of line

    Customer A[]=new Customer[size];

    for (int k=0; k<size; k++)
    {
        //read a name = 16 characters
        infile.useDelimiter("");
        name="";

        for (int i=0; i<16; i++) name=name+infile.next();
        infile.reset();

        purchase=infile.nextDouble();
        rebate=infile.nextDouble();
        if (infile.hasNextLine()) infile.nextLine(); //skip end of line

        A[k]=new Customer(name, purchase, rebate); //create object for A[i]

     } //end for loop

    infile.close();
    return A;

  } //end readArray

  //the method prints the Customer objects of the array A
  //one customer record per line
  private static void printArray(Customer [] A)
  {
   for (Customer x:A)
    {System.out.println(x);}
  } //end printArray
}  //end class prog4


class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>
{
  String name;
  double purchase;
  double rebate;

  public Customer(String n, double p, double r)
  { name=n;
    purchase=p;
    rebate=r;
  } //end Constructor

  public Customer(String n)
  { 
    name=n;
  } //end Constructor

  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("%-20s%10.2f%10.2f", name, purchase, rebate);
  }

public int compareTo(Customer a, Customer b) 
 {return b.name.compareTo(a.name);}
  }
//end class Customer

class descendingPurchase implements Comparator<Customer>
{
 public int compare(Customer a, Customer b)
   {
     if(a.purchase<b.purchase) return 1;
     else if(a.purchase==b.purchase) return 0;
     else return -1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Customer` implements [`Comparable<Customer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
class Customer implements Comparable<Customer>
```

which requires that you implement the following method

```
public int compareTo(Customer that)
```

Note the single argument. It is supposed to compare `this` against `that`.

Answer (score 0):

According to doc of the `Comparable<T>` interface, the method you should override is

```
 public int compareTo(T o)
```

in which the first object for the comparison is `this`.

You are defining

```
 public int compareTo(Customer a, Customer b)
```

which doesn't override the right method. That's why Java compiler is complaining about the fact that you stated that `Customer` implements `Comparable<Customer>` but you are actually missing the correct method.

The latter is the method required for a `Comparator<Customer>`, which offers the same functionality but in an "object-indipendent" way.

Answer (score 0):

when you implement an interface you *MUST* use exactly the method signature provided by it. The point of implementing interfaces is to let others know you have implemented the necessary methods they need. In your case you have a method that happens to have the same name declared in the interface, but is not the one expected by classes that know how to handle `Comparable`.

Imagine you have to write a class that invokes the `compareTo` method on other objects. You expect to pass a single param (of type T) and people keep implementing their own version, with all sorts of param types (Strings, ints, Comparables, etc.) and a varying quantity of them, for example `compareTo(boolean b, String s, int minMatches)`

`compareTo(float f, boolean caseSensitive)`

how could you know which one to call ?